# How to in XPages make shared library in javascript server side

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to do several databases that have repeated JavaScript Server Side functions. I would like to merge them into a single database and can use it for all. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Design inheritance is the classic way as Lothar pointed out and it works well. If you are not afraid of Java, you could create an OSGi plug-in (a.k.a an Extension library) that not only hosts your common SSJS, but your common custom controls, Java beans, resources etc. Get started with the [XSP Starter Kit](https://github.com/the-ntf/xspstarterkit) - Other than the name suggest, it is not designed for you to get started in Java, but for a developer sound in Java to get started with XPages extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find several posts dealing with similar topics; one of the most recent ones is this here:

[How Does the Single Store Xpages work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485441/how-does-the-single-store-xpages-work)

Magic words could be **Single Store Xpages Design** and **Notes Database templates**